# UPDATING table with another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

i have two tables `main_table` and `new_data` and i would like to update `main_table` by data from `new_data` table as you can see there are several empty places in time column in `main_table`. It should be fill in by data from `new_data` table. The 3rd table is the result. What is the best solution for this?

```
main_table
---------------------
id | name     | time
---------------------
 1 | tom      | 60
 2 | daniel   | 30
 3 | monica   | 42
 4 | gabriela | 
 5 | rachel   |
 6 | michael  | 15
 7 | adriana  | 
---------------------

new_data
--------------------
id | name     | time
--------------------
 1 | gabriela | 22
 2 | rachel   | 15
 3 | adriana  | 17
--------------------


main_table - updated by new_data - it should be result
---------------------
id | name     | time
---------------------
 1 | tom      | 60
 2 | daniel   | 30
 3 | monica   | 42
 4 | gabriela | 22
 5 | rachel   | 15
 6 | michael  | 15
 7 | adriana  | 17
---------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE new_data t1, JOIN main_table t2
SET t2.Time=t1.Time
WHERE t2.name=t1.name
```